# Background image with focal point

Tags: css, background-image

I have a map image which I would like to use as the background for my website. I would like it to cover the whole background (no white space, no scroll bars - most of the time, more on that later). However, there is a section of the map which I would like to never be cropped as I plan to overlay it with other information.

I have tried the following css:

```
html {
    background: url('../images/doreyfarmfullbackgroundempty2.png') no-repeat 90% 60% local; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
```

Can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkcsu5st/). The section I'd like to keep is the large yellowish section to the right of the image.

This works quite well for keeping the section of my background image in the frame most of the time but it still gets cut out when the window is resized to very short or very wide. In this situation I would like scroll bars to be introduced so that the whole 'focal point' can still be seen.

I know this is pretty niche but I was wondering if anyone can see a neat way of doing this?

Comment: What about having: `background: url('http://s2.postimg.org/kzwt9n34p/doreyfarmfullbackgroundempty2.png') no-repeat right top local; ` and it will always sit to the right. then you can position absolute/fixed something to the right and they should stay together as the page responds do different screen sizes - http://jsfiddle.net/xkcsu5st/1/

Comment: Thanks for help @Andrew but that still has the same problem. It is possible to resize the window such that the yellow section is cropped. I had 'right top' to start with but changed to those percentages because they seem to leave it uncropped for most amount of time possible.

Comment: You would need to do an @ media screen and change the % position when it moves of screen. So if it looses its position at like 400px screen width then do an @ media screen and move it another % so its in focus again.

Comment: I don't think that will work either as, for example, when the window is very wide and short -  it can be cropped both top and bottom so regardless of choice of vertical %, cropping will occur. Thats why I need to introduce the scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of you background pic, set min-witdh and min-height with that.

```
html{
    background: url('http://s2.postimg.org/kzwt9n34p/doreyfarmfullbackgroundempty2.png') ; 
    min-width:1000px;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkcsu5st/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Place the background image in a container, and give it a minimum width and height, with overflow set to auto.  So when the size of the browser forces the container to be smaller than you'd like, scroll bars appear allowing the user to pan the map.

```
<div class="map"></div>
```

and your CSS:

```
div.map {
  background: url('http://s2.postimg.org/kzwt9n34p/doreyfarmfullbackgroundempty2.png') no-repeat 90% 60% local; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
  overflow: auto;    <-- this will enable scrollbars on overflow
  min-height: 400px; <-- adjust this to taste
  min-width: 400px;  <-- and this
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Update to your fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xkcsu5st/2/

You could always augment this with a bit of script to control the scroll position of the map, so that the portion you want visible is always in view.

Comment: Thanks very much. This pretty much works. I can set min-height and min-width so that it is never cropped but now the image is sometimes smaller than it needs to be. I think maybe I need to set the min-height based on the window width and min-width based on window height which I guess I could fairly easily with a script?

Comment: Yeah you could figure out the right proportion using trial and error, and then set the container's calculated `min-width` and `min-height` on page load, and potentially on window resize.

Comment: Actually your updated fiddle led me to a potentially better solution using vh and vw to set the height and width. Another updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xkcsu5st/6/. The scroll bars seem to be working when I make it too short but not when I make it too narrow though...

Comment: Its working now: http://jsfiddle.net/xkcsu5st/7/. Just needed different numbers for some reason. Whats the protocol here. Should I accept your answer? Or can you edit it and then I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery library that does it with images instead of background-images:

https://github.com/jonom/jquery-focuspoint

It might not be the best answer in time but it seems to be for now. I'll post another answer if I have one for I think there might be a better way which I'm researching at the moment :)!